# analysis services error: the attribute key could not be found

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, ssas-2008

I am having an issue with my cube processing.  It is failing in production after I made an update to the view used to build one of my dimensions. Here are the steps I took:

- The update added a single field and did not touch anything else that was already present.
- I updated the cube dimension in BIDS and did a full process of the cube successfully.
- I have a scheduled job that reprocesses the cube every 15 mins and it
  ran for 16 hours without issue.
- Then the job started failing with the error "could not find attribute key". 
   The key it could not find was the ID column.
   The ID column already existed, and is a numeric column.
- I double checked to make sure there were no null ID fields, and there weren't.
- The ID field was aliased in the data source view, so I tried updating the table definition to use a named query and aliasing the ID field directly in the query.
- When I did that, I started getting errors that it could not find the [ID] field ( the
  original field name).

Eventually I had to roll the changes back because I couldn't figure out the cause and I had to get production back up. Now, 17 hours later, the processing of the cube is failing again when no changes have been made. I'm getting the error now that the attribute key cannot be found when processing .  When I look for the actual ID value that it gives me in the error, I find it in both of the views that make up my dimension and my fact table. 
My underlying data source is Oracle 11g. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This error means that your fact table is referencing a foreign key value that it can't find in your dimension table.   However, as you say that you are able to see the key in both the fact table and in the dimension table, I don't know what to tell you.   Maybe the dimension view that you are looking in isn't the one that your cube is looking in.   Maybe it's showing you the wrong ID.  Do a query to see if there are ANY FK values in the fact table that don't have a matching PK in the dimension view.

Answer (score 0):

Can you process the updated dimension(if you can restore the production db and BIDs project on local environment) ? check if it gives any error in dimension processing. Then try processing the related measure group alone and then try processing the complete cube and OLAP db. You will be able to find the error step more specifically and could be of help for analysis.
Also you can check this..

http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.in/2009/01/ssas-quick-reference-attribute-key.html